# how to make a css gradient stop after so many pixels?

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

```
-moz-radial-gradient(center -200px , ellipse farthest-corner, #323C49 0%, #718299 65%) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

I have this code above and i just realized that this gradient goes from top to bottom. Is there any way to make it stop the whole gradient after 30px. I can make adjustments as necessary, but how do you get the gradients to complete itself after 30px?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `background-size` property together.

like this:

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner, #323C49 0%, #718299 65%) no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 30px;
    background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: love this way. only thing that should be noted is that you have to add background-repeat:no-repeat; :] ty

Comment: oh never mind your example had that already... lol. Thanks again

Comment: background-repeat:no-repeat seems to be necessary. :)

Answer (score 8):

In CSS3:

```
radial-gradient(ellipse at center center, 
  rgb(30, 87, 153) 0%, rgb(41, 137, 216) 100px, 
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 101px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%)
```

You can have multiple stops in the gradient. You can also specify length in pixels rather than percentages. You can also use **rgba** to make transparent colours.

You start with your first colour at 0%, the center.
Then you have the second colour at *x* pixels (I'm using x=100 pixels here).
Then you go to transparent white at *x+1* pixels.
And stay transparent all the way until 100%.

this should work in browsers that support CSS3.

Answer (score 3):

css3 gradients are background images so they will fill the entire height and width of the block element, just as if it were a solid color.

In order to limit the height of the gradient, limit the height of the element. A "clean" way to do this might be to use a pseudo element. Something like...

```
div {height: 500px; width: 500px; position: relative}

div:before {
     content: " ";
     width: 100%;
     height: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: -1;
     display: block;
     background-image: [your-gradient-here]
}
```

Comment: when doing this on bootstrap .panel-body, i had to set the z-index of the div with the content to 0, or the gradient div would be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as long as the rest of the gradient (after your set number of pixels) can be a fixed color, just use three color stops as follows (this e.g. stops at 30px - notice the last entry is identical to the second):

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(90,90,90,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 30px,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%);
```

Comment: **This**. Add background`-image` and woosh you can combo it on the same line as background color :)